# Parse the contents of a Coldfusion variable into separate variables

Tags: regex, parsing, coldfusion

OK, so I've been banging my head against this one for a while and getting nowhere. I've been attempting to take the contents of a variable and parse the contained string into parts that would then be ingested into 5 separate variables. Seems simple enough right? Well, it has not proven to be simple at all, at least for me.

So I have a variable (PageContent) that contains the trimmed content from a CFHTTP request.
The PageContent variable now contains:

```
<tdnowrapalign=right>07/18/2020 13:00</td>
<tdalign=right>1002.12</td>
<tdalign=right>2,874,887</td>
<tdalign=right>12,766</td>
<tdalign=right>13,038</td>
```

It seems like there should be an easy way to write a loop that would loop over the tags in the "PageContent" variable assigning the content of each tag to a different variable. But every way I try to parse the data in the variable I either get an error (Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values.) or I end up with the content that I originally had in the "PageContent" variable repeated within the loop.

For instance, if I had a loop that would run through 5 iterations and could grab the contents of the tags assigning each to a variable then the desired result would be:

```
DateTime = "07/18/2020 13:00"
Elevation = "1002.12"
Storage = "2,874,887"
Outflow = "12,766"
Inflow = "13,038"
```

After trying every example I could find here and elsewhere online I'm now on something like my 100th attempt. Now I'm trying to use regular expressions to grab the contents of the tags and assign them to variables but no luck there. What I ended up with was the entire contents of the PageContent variable being stuffed into each one of the variables. The result was not really unexpected since I don't know of a way to differentiate between the 3 identical "tdalign" tags, but still it seems like at least the first variable would have worked since the tag was different "tdnowrapalign".

```
<cfset i=5/>
<cfloop index = "LoopCount" from = "1" to = #i#> 
    <cfif i EQ 1>
        <cfset dataDateTime = Replace(PageContent, "<[tdnowrapalign][^>]*>(.+?)</[td]>","","ALL")>
    <cfelseif i EQ 2>
        <cfset elevation = Replace(PageContent, "<[tdalign][^>]*>(.+?)</[td]>","","ALL")>
    <cfelseif i EQ 3>
        <cfset storage = Replace(PageContent, "<[tdalign][^>]*>(.+?)</[td]>","","ALL")>
    <cfelseif i EQ 4>
        <cfset outflow = Replace(PageContent, "<[tdalign][^>]*>(.+?)</[td]>","","ALL")>
    <cfelseif i EQ 5>
        <cfset inflow = Replace(PageContent, "<[tdalign][^>]*>(.+?)</[td]>","","ALL")>
    </cfif>

    <cfoutput>
    <cfif isdefined("dataDateTime")>
        dataDateTime = #dataDateTime#<br>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("elevation")>
        elevation = #elevation#<br>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("storage")>
        storage = #storage#<br>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("outflow")>
        outflow = #outflow#<br>
    </cfif>
    <cfif isdefined("inflow")>
        inflow = #inflow#<br>   
    </cfif>
    </cfoutput>

    <cfset i = i - 1> 

</cfloop>
```

Does anyone know if there is a way to get to the desired outcome I described where I end up with 5 variables containing the contents of the tags contained within the "PageContent" variable?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://www.bennadel.com/blog/779-parsing-html-tag-data-into-a-coldfusion-structure.htm

Comment: A regex or list functions may work for this specific case, but may break with others. Especially if screen scraping volatile content. For broader use, try JSoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it would be like this

```
<cfset PageContent = '<tdnowrapalign=right>07/18/2020 13:00</td>
<tdalign=right>1002.12</td>
<tdalign=right>2,874,887</td>
<tdalign=right>12,766</td>
<tdalign=right>13,038</td>' />

<cfset data = ListToArray(PageContent, '</td>', false, true) />

<cfset DateTime = ListLast(data[1], '>') />
<cfset Elevation = ListLast(data[2], '>') />
<cfset Storage = ListLast(data[3], '>') />
<cfset Outflow = ListLast(data[4], '>') />
<cfset Inflow = ListLast(data[5], '>') />
```

Demo: https://trycf.com/gist/b4f3b630bd1cbdc505d07a7d79b68ef5/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was trying to accomplish. This works beautifully and is so concise. I'm not sure exactly what you did but it looks sort of like what I've used when I am accessing a node in deserialized Json or a node in XML. Am I at all close in that description? And thank you so much for taking the time to provide a great solution.

Comment: Glad to help. List functions are great to use on strings sometimes. Next, since the values seem related you could group them in a structure (key/value pairs) if you want to make the code more elegant. Cheers.